# textbox blur jquery doesn't triggered after postback

Tags: jquery, textbox, updatepanel, blur

I'm calling a jquery onblur for a textbox that exist inside an updatepanel

as following

```
  $(".TextBox").blur(function () {
             $("#Image1").hide();
             $("#lbldone").hide();
         });
```

by debugging the function is being called properly but after postback function isn't being called at all.

this site is built using jquery 1.3 .. can anyone help me know what's the problem ?!

Comment: As I understood your `.hide(..)` element statements are not getting fired?

Comment: yup but the whole function isn't fired , sounds like textbox hasn't blur function ..

Comment: But if you wrote that the function is being called properly then why you say that? Did you checked your browser console?

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like? Maybe there is something wrong in there?

Comment: @OscarJara: i've user browser debugger and VS debugger .